# Safely connect Adafruit's powerboost 1000C LBO to rPi-GPIO

Tags: power, power-supply, adafruit

I would like to connect Adafruit's powerboost 1000C LBO control pin to a rPi GPIO-pin. So I can gracefully shutdown my rPi when the LiPo runs low.

I would like to connect the LBO to a diode to lower the voltage from 4.2 max down to 3.6 Volts and connect the 3.6 Volts directly to a GPIO pin.

**Q** Is this a reasonable and safe way to connect the LBO to a GPIO-pin? Are there any hazards I need to take into account?

An even simpler solution would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: The Pi GPIO should not be exposed to voltages greater than 3V3.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/284009) provides a nifty solution for my problem.

Comment: You may want to check out the answers to [a similar question for connecting the LBO pin of a Powerboost 500 to an RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/42946).